# Google maps css height

Tags: css, google-maps, popup

I'm trying to set map height according to page height. In my case, i have pop-up window, which contains two divs: on the left is "directions" div, which can be higher than popup window and is normal scrolable, on the right is map-direction. Map is full height of popup, but when i scroll down, i get white stripe at the bottom. Link (when open, re-size it down to smaller window and try mentioned):

[Link to page](http://www.grta-studio.com/diplomska/domov/direction?lat=46.0569465&lng=14.5057515&lat_f=46.052479&lng_f=14.609548)

HTML:

```
<div class="search_box">
    <div id="header">
        <img src="<?php echo base_url('images/logo.jpg'); ?> ">
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <div id="directions">
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>

        <div id="map_box">
            <div id="slo_map">
                <?php echo $map['html']; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS

```
.search_box {
    width: 390px;
    float: left;
    min-height: 800px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#header {
    height: 121px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;

}
.search_box .content {
    padding: 15px;
}
#directions {
    background-color: white;
    float: left;
    width:350px;
    height: 100%;
}
#slo_map {
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#map_box {
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-left: 1px solid #6d6d6d;
}
```

popup javascript:

```
function popup(mylink, windowname)
    {
        if (! window.focus)return true;
        var href;
        if (typeof(mylink) == 'string')
            href=mylink;
        else
            href=mylink.href;
        window.open(href, windowname, 'width=1200,height=800,scrollbars=yes');
        return false;
    }
```

Any ideas how to regularly set css to show map with full height of page, not just visible window?

Thank you!

Comment: can you post relevant code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The opposite approach might fit your needs: set the sidebar to 100% height and let the overflowing content scroll.

```
.search_box {
    width: 390px;
    float: left;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```